# uib-carousel active not updating on sliding

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, d3.js

So I am trying to have a `uib-carousel` which host separate `<div>` as it's item, and I am hoping to draw some D3 graphs on each slide.

**My code:-**

```
  <div id = "myCarousel">
          <div uib-carousel interval="1000" active="active">
              <div uib-slide index="0" >
                <div id ="d3-part1"></div>
              </div>
              <div uib-slide index="1" >
                <div id = "d3-part2"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

*Note:* I am not using `ng-repeat` inside `uib-slide`, as I want to try out this way.

**My Problem:-**

The first slide is shown perfectly, so does the second slide, but I would like to know when the slide2, here *div id* `d3-part2` is visible so I can draw D3 on that div. Doing the `$scope.$watch` on active shows no log.

```
$scope.$watch('active', function(){
            console.log('active: ', $scope.active);
});
```

What may the problem here?